# 301 redirect with if/else statements

Tags: php, redirect, http-status-code-301, if-statement

I would like to make a php 301 redirect based upon if else statement.
I have 2 categories and would like pages within category 2 redirect to another url.

Is it possible to have all pages of category 2 redirect from domain1.com to domain2.com?

So also :::: domain1.com/pagetitle.html to domain2.com/pagetitle.html?

I have the following, but it doesnt seem to work. The in_category is okay, but the redirect is only the base url domain2.com and not domain2.com/pagetitle.html:

```
if (in_category('2') ){
Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" ); 
header('Location: http://www.markett.nl' . $url_suffix . '/' . $url, true, 301); 
} else { }
```

**----------------- EDIT ------------------------------------**

This is still driving me crazy...

I have the following, but firefox says there is a problem while loading through some cookies.

Is this the right markup??

```
<?php $category = get_the_category();
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

// Redirect to correct site on basis of section id
if(in_category('2') ){ 
header('Location: http://www.domain2.com/' . $url, true, 301); 
exit; } 
?>
```

[SEE THIS IMAGE](http://rphgoossens.files.wordpress.com/2010/06/screenshot-problem-loading-page-mozilla-firefox.png) of what I get redirected too.

Comment: What is `$url_suffix` and what is `$url`? See also [`wp_redirect`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect).

Comment: `header('Location:...')` automatically sets an HTTP 301 btw.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the $_SERVER vars to find out which one you need: [Reserved variables $_SERVER](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

To make things easier:

```
var_dump($_SERVER);
die();
```

Add this before your code (one time) to find out what the variables consist of. I'm not giving the full answer as it is also good to learn about these variables.

Answer (score 0):

### Question

> Is it possible to have all pages of category 2 redirect from domain1.com to domain2.com?

Yes.

### Possible solutions

#### Call `exit` after `header()`

You need to `exit` after issuing the header for it to be sent immediately.

#### Pass the status code into `header()`

Also [`header()` <sup>DOCs</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) can be passed the HTTP status code as the third parameter instead of making two calls to `header()`:

> Forces the HTTP response code to the specified value. Note that this
>   parameter only has an effect if the string is not empty.

### Code

So the code looks like:

```
if(in_category('2') ){
    header('Location: http://www.domain2.nl' . $url_suffix . '/' . $url, true, 301);
    exit;
}
```